# Null model AIC lower than full model AIC in logistic regression in R

Tags: r, logistic, aic

I am looking for an interpretation for a result from real data:

I ran a basic binary classification using logistic regression in R. Given some number of explanatory variables and the dependent variable (DV), what would be the interpretation for an null model (i.e. the DV and just the intercept) having a *lower* a AIC value than the full model (i.e. the DV and all available explanatory variables)?

```
fit_null = glm(formula=DV ~ 1, data=data, family="binomial")

> Null deviance: 708.49  on 525  degrees of freedom Residual deviance:
> 708.49  on 525  degrees of freedom **AIC: 710.49**

fit_full = glm(formula=DV ~ ., data=data, family="binomial")

> Null deviance: 708.49  on 525  degrees of freedom Residual deviance:
> 620.86  on 465  degrees of freedom **AIC: 742.86**
```

I have run a model similar to this on a completely separate data set which returned AIC values for the full model significantly lower than the null: null AIC was over 1000, full model AIC was just over 300. I would have expected similar behavior for the second data set (given that it is very similar data) and I am unsure what to make of the output.

Answer (score 11):

There's nothing special about this situation that would make its interpretation any different. The null model is better than the complete model according to the AIC -- the marginal improvement of the full regression is not worth its degrees of freedom, and appears more like random variance than real trends, on the whole. Although no metric like the AIC should be complete relied on by itself, the model is clearly far too complex. You should try a regression with a subset of explanatory variables, preferably using some well-defined variable selection procedure like ridge regression or the lasso.